# Turtlebot Installtion help

Tags: ros, roslaunch, turtlebot, turtlebot-bringup, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Whenever I try to use the code roslaunch turtlebot_bringup minimal launch

I get an error that says that it cannot locate minimal in package turtlebot_bringup
what do I do?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57566/turtlebot-installtion-help/) by [smkybear15](https://answers.ros.org/users/4388/smkybear15/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-03-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Add a `.` (dot) between minimal and launch.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-03-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2